# Is there an easier way to print a users input from an input statement?

Tags: python, validation, input

I simply want to reprint what the user enters for -Wordinput-, what I have now works fine but is there an easier way in which I can do this? Please help!

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
        'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
        'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

wordInput = input('Print your word: ')
for i in range(len(wordInput)):
    indivLetter = wordInput[i].lower()
    finalWord = [match for match in list if indivLetter in match]
    print(*finalWord, end='')
```

Comment: If you want to reprint the word, then why not just `print(wordInput)`?

Comment: Or, if you want to print it out in lower case: `print(wordInput.lower())`

Comment: Do you try to *filter* some non-ascii letter?  We can guess, but rather you can explain and confirm here.  Would be helpful to show some *sample* words here.

Comment: Something like this - ```finalWord = ''.join(ch for ch in wordInput.lower() if ch in lower_case)```    lower_case is your *list*.  (Don't use built-in *list* as variable name)

Comment: There is `string.ascii_lowercase` to avoid enumerating digits by hand (`import string`, standard library). To filter only lowercase ASCII letters from input, you can just `print(''.join(v for v in wordInput.lower() if v in string.ascii_lowercase))`. You can also use `if v.isascii()` to filter ASCII-only characters, or some other of a bunch of string `is***` methods (`isalpha`, `isdigit`, ...)

Comment: Wow.  I didn't think it would be that simple...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`